# Encrypted Data in MySql

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have a JAVA application (Jersey, Hibernate, Spring) which is using MySql as database. Application is running completely fine. Now my client wants me to encrypt all data in database  because it hold some confidential information as well. so for example if anybody directly logs in to MySQL he/she should not be able to view actual data but the encrypted data.

Actual data should be shown in correct for only using application.(In application we are maintaining user rights).

Please suggest do I need to make change at application layer. Application is quite big and if make changes for each and every query while inserting and retrieving data, it would take alot of time. Please suggest if there is any alternative way.

Regards,
Alex

Comment: Change the database passwords? This request makes little sense. Why on earth would someone without privileges to see the data be allowed to log in from the command line and poke around?

Comment: You will have to change your persistence layer to encrypt only relevant data before persisting.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL does not provide transparent data encryption by default. I quick googling reveals some add on products that claim to do what you are looking for (personally, do not have any experience with them):

- [zNcrypt for MySQL](http://www.gazzang.com/products/zncrypt/mysql)
- [MyDiamo](http://www.mydiamo.com/)

I think you should evaluate these options.